# ¿Cómo solucionar un error de string vacio en docker?

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, log, logger

Tengo un esquema client-broker-worker del que me gustaría llevar un registro de los mensajes que se envían mediante un archivo llamado "log" pero como estoy usando docker tengo que usar un "volume" para persistir la información. Para crear el archivo y escribir en él he escrito un código muy simple que se limita a escribir en el fichero lo que se le pasa:

```
//logger
const {zmq, lineaOrdenes, traza, error, adios, creaPuntoConexion} = require('../tsr')
lineaOrdenes("loggerPort filename")
// logger in NodeJS
// First argument is port number for incoming messages
// Second argument is file path for appending log entries

const fs = require('fs');
let log = zmq.socket('pull')

creaPuntoConexion(log, loggerPort)
log.on('message', (text) => {fs.appendFileSync(filename, text+'\n')})
```

Como estoy usando docker he creado un dockerfile para este código y como me interesa que la ubicación del "log" sea dinámica he usado una variable de entorno ($LOGGER_DIR) que se sustituirá mediante un archivo docker-compose.

```
//Dockerfile
FROM tsr-zmq
COPY ./tsr.js tsr.js
RUN mkdir logger
WORKDIR logger
COPY ./logger.js mylogger.js
VOLUME $LOGGER_DIR
EXPOSE 9995
CMD node mylogger 9995 $LOGGER_DIR/logs
```

El problema lo obtengo al tratar de crear una imagen de este dockerfile. Cada vez que ejecuto `docker built -t logger .` obtengo:

```
ser@tsr-vbox-2324b:~/Escritorio/Práctica_TSR_3/tsr_lab3_material/CBWL/logger$ docker build -t logger .
[+] Building 0.2s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 205B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/tsr-zmq:latest                                                                                                                                             0.0s
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR logger
   5 |     COPY ./logger.js mylogger.js
   6 | >>> VOLUME $LOGGER_DIR
   7 |     EXPOSE 9995
   8 |     CMD node mylogger 9995 $LOGGER_DIR/logs
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: VOLUME specified can not be an empty string
```

No entiendo por qué dice que es un string vacío si precisamente va a ser sustituido cuando ejecute `docker-compose up`.
Dejo por aquí el código del docker-compose.yml por si sirve.

```
services:
//other services
log:
    image: logger
    build: ./logger/
    expose:
      - "9995"
    volumes:
# /tmp/logger.log DIRECTORY must exist on host and writeable
      - /tmp/logger.log:/tmp/cbwlog
    environment:
      - LOGGER_DIR=/tmp/cbwlog
```